# How can I access canvas color via python

Tags: python, kivy

I want to change the background screen color for different cases.
How can I access the canvas color via python...

Thanks
Julius

I've tried it with this:

```
        with self.canvas:
            if time == times_list[6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 or 11 or 12]:
                Color(rgb=utils.get_color_from_hex("#d18154ff"))
            if time == times_list[13 or 14 or 15 or 16 or 17]:
                Color(rgb=utils.get_color_from_hex("#00b6fffff"))
            if time == times_list[18 or 19 or 20 or 21]:
                Color(rgb=utils.get_color_from_hex("#b46e46ff"))
            if time == times_list[22 or 23 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6]:
                Color(rgb=utils.get_color_from_hex("#000000a8"))
```

```
<DuesseldorfWindow>:
    name: "DueW"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb : utils.get_color_from_hex("#00b6fffff")
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas doesn't have a colour, rather it's a list of instructions to run one by one in order to draw your app. The Color instruction sets an internal context variable to say that *if* something is drawn *then* it will take that colour.

With that in mind, your top piece of code is probably just adding Color instructions to the canvas that don't do anything, as they come after everything else that's drawn. Instead you need to change the rgb value of the Color instruction in your second piece of code.

I suggest adding a `colour = ListProperty(get_color_from_hex("x00b6ffff"))` declaration to your DusseldorfWindow class, then writing `rgb: root.colour` in the kv. Then later when you want to change the colour you write `self.colour = ...` to *change* the colour that's already being used instead of adding a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I get an error still:  ...
      11:    canvas.before:
      12:        Color:
 >>   13:            rgb : root.colour
      14:        Rectangle:
      15:            pos: self.pos
 ...
 AttributeError: 'DuesseldorfWindow' object has no attribute 'colour'